# VHDL code IF statement using a With XXX select also

Tags: vhdl, quartus

HELP with my  VHDL code
trying to select what input go to the output with a IF statement
using a WITH XXX Select

s is the select
d and e
are for the 4 input
y is the output

Help 
Thanks

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;



ENTITY mux_4_1 IS
PORT(
S : in STD_LOGIC;
d : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
e : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
y : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 to 6));



END mux_4_1;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF mux_4_1 is
BEGIN
PROCESS(S,d,e)
BEGIN
   IF S = '0' THEN

      WITH d SELECT

      y <=      "1111110" WHEN "0000",--0
                "0110000" WHEN "0001",--1
                "1101101" WHEN "0010",--2
                "1111001" WHEN "0011",--3
                "0110011" WHEN "0100",--4
                "1011011" WHEN "0101",--5
                "1011111" WHEN "0110",--6
                "1110000" WHEN "0111",--7
                "1111111" WHEN "1000",--8
                "1111011" WHEN "1001",--9
                 "0000000" when others;



ELSE S = '1' THEN

      WITH e SELECT

      y <=      "1111110" WHEN "0000",--0
                "0110000" WHEN "0001",--1
                "1101101" WHEN "0010",--2
                "1111001" WHEN "0011",--3
                "0110011" WHEN "0100",--4
                "1011011" WHEN "0101",--5
                "1011111" WHEN "0110",--6
                "1110000" WHEN "0111",--7
                "1111111" WHEN "1000",--8
                "1111011" WHEN "1001",--9
                 "0000000" when others;


END IF;
END PROCESS;
END behavior;
```

> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at mux_4_1.vhd(23) near text "WITH"; expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("with" is a reserved keyword), or a sequential statement
>   Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at mux_4_1.vhd(25) near text "WHEN"; expecting ";"

Comment: You're missing a **clear problem statement** part of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). *Help* lacks specificity. What error message are you getting doing what? Please show the specific error message.

Comment: Info: Running Quartus II Analysis & Synthesis
 Info: Version 9.1 Build 350 03/24/2010 Service Pack 2 SJ Web Edition
 Info: Processing started: Sat Jul 16 20:50:13 2016
Info: Command: quartus_map --read_settings_files=on --write_settings_files=off mux_4_1 -c mux_4_1
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at mux_4_1.vhd(23) near text "WITH";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("with" is a reserved keyword), or a sequential statement
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at mux_4_1.vhd(25) near text "WHEN";  expecting ";"

Comment: The `ELSE` should be an `ELSIF`, it's followed by a condition which should be followed by a `THEN`.

Comment: Please add your Info to your question, comments are frangible.  Besides the `elsif` you don't appear to be have -2008 compatibility for sequential selected signal assignment from the error message. A search shows II 9.1 had preliminary support for -2008, not clear what. Use a case statement in place of each selected signal assignment statement.

Comment: Sequential (in a process or subprogram) support for selected signal assignments is introduced in IEEE Std 1076-2008, which is still not widely or fully supported as yet. A selected signal assignment statement presents a case statement equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only mistake I can see from what you gave is that there is no `then` after an `else` statement.

Comment: That `else` should be an `elsif`, which requires a `then` following the condition.

Comment: Thanks for the help i did change it and i still get a error.  Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at mux_4_1.vhd(23) near text "WITH";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("with" is a reserved keyword), or a sequential statement  .  -------     I am trying to get the d and e bits to change what 4 bits select the output. Thanks again